# For-loop only returns last value

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying this code on python:

```
N = 5

for n in xrange (0, N):
    a = [10 + n]
    
print(a[0])
```

The code returns `14`, and when I try to `print(a[1])` I have a list index error. What I want is to be able to view `a[0]`, `a[1]` ... `a[n]`. When I write `a=[10 + n for n in xrange (0,N)]` it works but I don't understand the difference. Can anyone help on how to make the first method work?

Comment: You're reassigning `a` to a new list each time through the loop, which discards its previous value.

Comment: You should *really* switch to Python 3, as Python 2 is only of interest to those needing to maintain code that cannot (for some reason) be migrated to Python 3.

Comment: Actually my python code is linked to my Dymola(Modelica) model and it only works with python 2 as far as I know

Answer (score 3):

You aren't appending to a list; you are repeatedly redefining which single-element list `a` refers to.

```
a = []
for n in range(N):
    a.append(10 + n)
```